# Activity pops instead of adding a new one on stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this complicated problem in a project I am developing in Eclipse for Android 4.4 KitKat. I have developed an activity that shows the user three different types of activities for him to choose from, Easy Medium and Hard mode quizes. I have only one score activity that all three modes of quizes result at, calculating the total score of the user. The way to distiguish between the modes of quizes is that I am passing a string variable inside the intent of the activity, and in the score activity I have an if statement that matches if(activityString.equals("easy")) then calculate this scoring system. The problem is that when I am done with the questions inside the quiz mode, the score activity does not come on top of the stack and instead the previous activity (quiz main menu activity) on stack comes on top (pops the quiz activity).
Really complicated, wasn't sure if I could ask for such a complex problem, but here is my code:

Snippet of the code that checks if there exist more questions in the array list declared before. The answers are answered using radio buttons. in the first else statement is where the correct answers are calculated and then moving to the next activity desired, ScoreActivity
QuizActivity.java ( quiz main menu)

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RadioButton uansw = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String ansText = uansw.getText().toString();

                if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag]))
                {
                    correct++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
                //increment flag to show next question
                flag++;
                if(flag<questions.length)
                {
                    rb1.setChecked(true);
                    //change question text view to next question
                    tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                    //change radio button options to next value of the array
                    rb1.setText(opt[flag * 3]);
                    rb2.setText(opt[flag * 3 + 1]);
                    rb3.setText(opt[flag * 3 + 2]);

                }
                else 
                {
                    //shows negative marks if toggle is on
                    if(MainQuizActivity.tbflag )
                    {
                        marks = correct - wrong;
                    }
                    //if toggle is off
                    else
                    {
                        marks = correct;
                    }
                    finish();
                    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ScoreActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("activity", "easy");
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my ScoreActivity.java code snippet, related to easy mode quiz, fetching the score for the user's input

```
if(activityString.equals("easy"))
        {
            txtViewQuizCompleted.setText("You have successfully completed \nEasy Mode Quiz!");
            sb.append("Correct Answers:" + QuizActivity.correct);
            sb.append("\nWrong Answers:" + QuizActivity.wrong);
            sb.append("\nTime Left:" + timeLeft + "secs");
            sb.append("\n\nFinal SCORE: " + finalScore);
            //print values to textview
            tv.setText(sb);
            finish();
        }
```

sry for the too much information, tried to keep it as simple as possible. LogCat does not show anything, if more information requested, please let me know

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you saying the ScoreActivity doesn't show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is occurence and location of

```
finish();
```

In your quiz activity you call finish before you create and launch the ScoreActivity activity, hence killing the Quiz activity and going back to the previous activity before the ScoreActivity even has a chance to open.

In reality though, for some reason, sometimes it may actually manage to open up the ScoreActivity before it finishes killing itself, but then you  run into another problem; As soon as you set the score in the ScoreActivity you call finish() again and this effectively kills the activity.

So now the only activity left is the activity before the quiz one, which it goes back to.